# What is the order of adding eventlistener to a component and adding that component to a panel or frame?

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, mouse-listeners

Can a mouselistener be added to a component say JLabel after the JLabel has been added to the frame or panel ? Or eventlistener has to be added before adding the component to the panel or frame.

Comment: Are you having trouble with this, or is it just a general question? Only limitation is that you have to create the components before you add listener to them or you will catch a NPE. But you can add or change listeners to components before or after they are added to a panel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order shouldn't matter, since the user can't interact with the control until the current piece of code returns control to the system. Are you having trouble catching an event?

Comment: There was some trouble and I thought it might be because of the order. But you are correct order is immaterial. Problem was something else